# How to find file written in databricks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, databricks

I wrote a file using pickle

```
with open("file.txt", 'wb') as fp:
   pickle.dump(L, fp)
```

and I can easily open it when in the same notebook using

```
with open("file.txt", "rb") as fp:
   pickle.load(fp)
```

but when I want to do this from another notebook, I can't seem to find the file.  I've manually checked the FileStore and don't see it anywhere and I've used

```
%scala
dbutils.notebook.getContext().notebookPath.get
```

to get the current full path and tried that plus the filename, but that hasn't worked either.  I can't access it from the notebook the file was originally written from right now because its running something that's been running for the past 24 hours

Comment: what type of the cluster are you using? What the cluster restarted?